# Copying an absolute block range but updating the row numbers

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have the following data sheet

| E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 |
| 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 |
| 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.1 |

I would like to implement a conditional formatting formula that would:

- bold the maximum number of each row (i.e. `I1`, `H2`, `I3`, `G4` would be bold);
- bold+red the maximum number of each block, where a block consists of multiple rows - `E1:I2` is one block, `E3:I4` is another, etc. (i.e. `H2` and `G4` would be red + bold).

The first rule is easy to implement. I simply apply the condition `=E1=MAX($E1:$I1)` on the entire range `E:I`.

For the second rule, what I currently have is the condition `=E1=MAX($E$1:$I$2)` on the range `E:I`, however this only works for the first block. One way to solve it is to apply it to the range `E1:I2` instead, then copy the same formula to the range `E3:I4`, manually fix the row numbers in the condition, and repeat for every block below. However, there are quite a few blocks below, so this solution isn't ideal. Is there a better way of implementing this blockwise formatting?

## EDIT

A note on @doubleunary's accepted answer below - the answer only works for blocks of size 2 (i.e. 2 rows). For larger blocks (in my case of size 6) I had to use the following, more general formula (fortunately none of my cells are empty so I didn't have to worry about that part):

```
=E1=MAX(OFFSET($E1:$I6, -MOD(ROW(E1) - 1, 6), 0))
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `offset()`, `row()` and `iseven()`, like this:

`=isnumber(E1) * ( E1 = max(offset($E1:$I2, -iseven(row(E1)), 0)) )`

The `isnumber()` test prevents the conditional format from highlighting blank rows.

Comment: excellent :) . However, you must add a filter for the cells of the range that are empty, like: `=and (E1=max(offset ($E1:$I2, -iseven (row (E1))), 0)), E1<>"")`

Comment: Thanks. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Offset was indeed the key idea here, though I had to adapt this answer a little bit for my use-case (since in my actual, much larger datasheet, the blocks were actually bigger than 2 rows). I'm accepting this answer but editing my final solution into the question for posterity.